# Merge the values of two or more arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Someone could be so nice to tell me how to do the following with 2 ore more arrays in PHP:

```
array 1 (a,b,c,d)
array 2 (1,2,3,4)
```

I would like to merge the two arrays in an unique array with the merged values:

Result: unique `array (a-1,b-2,c-3,d-4)`.

Is there any function that does so? I could not find anything in the forum either on the web.

---

Thanks for all your answers but I guess that my arrays are a bit more structured because I need the final result for a dropdown field.
Now I have these 2 arrays:

```
$array1[] = array( 'text' => $hospital['value'], 'value' => $hospital['value'] );
$array2[] = array( 'text' => $company['value'], 'value' => $company['value'] );
```

I want to have a final array that contains: `Hospital1 - Company1, Hospital2 - Company2,  Hospital3 - Company3,` etc..

Thanks

Comment: a-1 is this pure value or key value pair like 'a' => 1 ?

Comment: It should be a pure value, and not a key. I want to combine more values from two structured arrays. I have written an example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a loop to do this manually. it might look something like the following:

```
$a = array(a,b,c,d);
$b = array(1,2,3,4);
$c = array(); //result set
if(count($a) == count($b)){ // make sure they are the same length
   for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){
      $c[] = $a[$i]."-".$b[$i];
   }
}
print_r($c);
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer but I guess that my arrays are a bit more structured because I need the final result for a dropdown field. Now I have these 2 arrays:

$array1[] = array( 'text' => $hospital['value'], 'value' => $hospital['value'] ); $array2[] = array( 'text' => $company['value'], 'value' => $company['value'] );

I want to have a final array that contains: Hospital1 - Company1, Hospital2 - Company2, Hospital3 - Company3, ecc..

Thanks

Comment: Its hard to understand with the array definitions you provide since they seem to each contain only 2 values, 'text' and 'value', which are defined by some other array. It sounds like you're telling me that you have nested arrays and that you only want one of the values from the second layer. If this is the case then it should simply be a matter if defining it in the loop like $a[$i]['text'] or $a[$i]['value']

Comment: Yeah!! Thanks a lot :) You made it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_map(function ($item1, $item2) {
    return "$item1-$item2";
}, $array1, $array2);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05f937f9c7bd9867222280c3b605e142e534f252).

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer, but my array is a bit more structured because I need it for a dropdown field:

$array1[] = array( 'text' => $hospital['value'], 'value' => $hospital['value'] );
$array2[] = array( 'text' => $company['value'], 'value' => $company['value'] );

I want to have a final array that contains: Hospital1 - Company1, Hospital2 - Company2,  Hospital3 - Company3, ecc..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, you can use array_combine where array 1 will be the key and array 2 the value.

Example usage:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(a,b,c,d);

$c = array_combine($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```